# Pandas DataFrame: How to change a column into an index, but this new index is a combination of both the current columns and indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As per title, I have a similar dataframe such as this:

```
    c0  c1  c2
i0  1   2   3
i1  40  50  60
```

And I would like transform it into something like this:

```
      items
i0 c0  1
i0 c1  2
i0 c2  3
i1 c0  40
i1 c1  50
i1 c2  60
```

I think this has to do with multiindexing or groupby but I don't really know where to start with this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) only:

```
df = df.stack()
print (df)
i0  c0     1
    c1     2
    c2     3
i1  c0    40
    c1    50
    c2    60
dtype: int64
```

Get `Multiindex`:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['i0', 'i1'], ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

For `one column DataFrame` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.stack().to_frame('items')
print (df)
       items
i0 c0      1
   c1      2
   c2      3
i1 c0     40
   c1     50
   c2     60
```

For `DataFrame` with columns created from `MultiIndex` use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index(name='items')
print (df)
    a   b  items
0  i0  c0      1
1  i0  c1      2
2  i0  c2      3
3  i1  c0     40
4  i1  c1     50
5  i1  c2     60
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping me with this one and my other question yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.